How to debug the saturation of regression task performance using GANs
I wanted to work on predicting the weather patterns using images, however, given the humongous nature of the actual data, I decided to train a model using a much simpler test dataset first. The test dataset is built using a radius array derived from absolute sine curve and each test sample is 3 continuous images(either increasing or decreasing radius) and the expected output is to predict the next image. Each image consists of 0's and 1's only with 1's filling the radius area and the remaining area being 0's.


The idea is that the model is supposed to learn the theta(the latent variable I believe) from the samples being shown during training. However, I extensively tested many hyperparameter possibilities and couldn't come up with better results than shown below. I'd like to know your thoughts on how to approach the problem to improve the performance in general? Am i making any wrong assumptions in believing that gans could be used in the regression context?

Please find the code below to reproduce the experiment
import glob
import json
from PIL import Image
import re
from typing import Sequence, List
import yaml

from flax.training.train_state import TrainState
import flax.linen as nn
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random, jit
from jax import vmap, value_and_grad
from loguru import logger
import optax
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score, root_mean_squared_error


class Downsample(nn.Module):
    filters: int
    kernel_size: Sequence[int]
    apply_batchnorm: bool = True

    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self, x, training):
        x = nn.Conv(
            self.filters, self.kernel_size, strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", kernel_init=nn.initializers.normal(0.02)
        )(x)
        if self.apply_batchnorm:
            x = nn.BatchNorm(use_running_average=not training)(x)
        x = nn.leaky_relu(x)
        return x


class Upsample(nn.Module):
    filters: int
    kernel_size: Sequence[int]
    apply_dropout: bool = False

    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self, x, training):
        x = nn.ConvTranspose(
            self.filters, self.kernel_size, strides=(2, 2), padding="SAME", kernel_init=nn.initializers.normal(0.02)
        )(x)
        x = nn.BatchNorm(use_running_average=not training)(x)
        if self.apply_dropout and training:
            x = nn.Dropout(0.5, deterministic=not training)(x)
        x = nn.relu(x)
        return x


class Generator(nn.Module):
    input_shape: Sequence[int]
    output_channels: int
    downsample_filters: Sequence[int]
    upsample_filters: Sequence[int]
    kernel_size: Sequence[int] = (4, 4)
    apply_dropout: bool = True

    def setup(self):
        self.down_stack = [
            Downsample(filters, self.kernel_size, apply_batchnorm=(i != 0))
            for i, filters in enumerate(self.downsample_filters)
        ]
        self.up_stack = [
            Upsample(filters, self.kernel_size, apply_dropout=(i < 3 and self.apply_dropout))
            for i, filters in enumerate(self.upsample_filters)
        ]

        self.last = nn.ConvTranspose(
            self.output_channels,
            self.kernel_size,
            strides=(2, 2),
            padding="SAME",
            kernel_init=nn.initializers.normal(0.02),
        )
        self.last_activation = nn.tanh

    def __call__(self, inputs, training):
        skips = []
        x = inputs
        for down in self.down_stack:
            x = down(x, training=training)
            skips.append(x)

        skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

        for up, skip in zip(self.up_stack, skips):
            x = up(x, training=training)
            x = jnp.concatenate([x, skip], axis=-1)

        x = self.last(x)
        x = self.last_activation(x)
        return x


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    input_shape: Sequence[int]
    output_channels: Sequence[int]
    downsample_filters: List[int]
    conv_filters: List[int]
    kernel_size: Sequence[int] = (4, 4)

    def setup(self):

        self.initial_conv = nn.Conv(
            self.conv_filters[0],
            self.kernel_size,
            strides=(2, 2),
            padding="SAME",
            kernel_init=nn.initializers.normal(0.02),
            use_bias=False,
        )
        self.leaky_relu = nn.leaky_relu

        self.down_stack = [Downsample(filters, self.kernel_size) for filters in self.downsample_filters]

        self.middle_conv = nn.Conv(
            self.conv_filters[1],
            self.kernel_size,
            strides=(2, 2),
            padding="SAME",
            kernel_init=nn.initializers.normal(0.02),
            use_bias=False,
        )
        self.middle_sigmoid = nn.sigmoid

        self.last_conv = nn.Conv(
            self.output_channels,
            self.kernel_size,
            strides=(2, 2),
            padding="SAME",
            kernel_init=nn.initializers.normal(0.02),
        )
        self.last_sigmoid = nn.sigmoid

    def __call__(self, input_image, target_image, training):
        x = jnp.concatenate([input_image, target_image], axis=-1)
        x = self.initial_conv(x)
        x = self.leaky_relu(x)

        for down in self.down_stack:
            x = down(x, training=training)

        x = self.middle_conv(x)
        x = self.middle_sigmoid(x)

        x = self.last_conv(x)
        x = self.last_sigmoid(x)
        return x


# Updated generator loss function
def generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target, lambda_constant):
    gan_loss = optax.sigmoid_binary_cross_entropy(disc_generated_output, jnp.ones_like(disc_generated_output)).mean()
    l1_loss = jnp.mean(jnp.abs(target - gen_output))
    total_loss = gan_loss + (lambda_constant * l1_loss)
    return total_loss, gan_loss, l1_loss


# Updated discriminator loss function
def discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output):
    real_loss = optax.sigmoid_binary_cross_entropy(disc_real_output, jnp.ones_like(disc_real_output)).mean()
    generated_loss = optax.sigmoid_binary_cross_entropy(
        disc_generated_output, jnp.zeros_like(disc_generated_output)
    ).mean()
    total_loss = real_loss + generated_loss
    return total_loss


@jit
def train_step(generator_state, discriminator_state, batch_inputs, batch_targets, key, lambda_constant):

    def gen_loss_fn(gen_params):
        gen_output = generator.apply(
            {"params": gen_params}, batch_inputs, mutable=["batch_stats"], rngs={"dropout": dropout_key}, training=True
        )
        disc_generated_output = discriminator.apply(
            {"params": discriminator_state.params}, batch_inputs, gen_output[0], mutable=["batch_stats"], training=False
        )
        total_loss, gan_loss, l1_loss = generator_loss(
            disc_generated_output[0], gen_output[0], batch_targets, lambda_constant
        )
        return total_loss, (gan_loss, l1_loss)

    def disc_loss_fn(disc_params):
        gen_output = generator.apply(
            {"params": generator_state.params},
            batch_inputs,
            mutable=["batch_stats"],
            rngs={"dropout": dropout_key},
            training=False,
        )
        disc_real_output = discriminator.apply(
            {"params": disc_params}, batch_inputs, batch_targets, mutable=["batch_stats"], training=True
        )
        disc_generated_output = discriminator.apply(
            {"params": disc_params}, batch_inputs, gen_output[0], mutable=["batch_stats"], training=True
        )
        total_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_output[0], disc_generated_output[0])
        return total_loss

    # Compute gradients for the discriminator
    disc_loss, disc_grads = value_and_grad(disc_loss_fn)(discriminator_state.params)
    discriminator_state = discriminator_state.apply_gradients(grads=disc_grads)

    # Compute gradients for the generator
    (gen_loss, (gan_loss, l1_loss)), gen_grads = value_and_grad(gen_loss_fn, has_aux=True)(generator_state.params)
    generator_state = generator_state.apply_gradients(grads=gen_grads)

    return generator_state, discriminator_state, gen_loss, gan_loss, l1_loss, disc_loss



config = {
    "random_seed": 0,
    "num_samples": 500,
    "offset": 1,  # 'y' is offset by 1 time step from 'x'
    "train_valid_test_splits": [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],  # in percentage of num of samples
    "log_validation_freq": 10,  # log validation data results for every x epochs
    "log_evaluation_freq": 10,  # log validation data evaluation for every x epochs
    "batch_size": 1,
    "learning_rate": 0.001,
    "decay_b1": 0.5,
    "decay_b2": 0.999,
    "lambda_constant": 100,
    "generator_config": {
        "downsample_filters": [8, 16, 32, 64, 64, 128, 128],
        "upsample_filters": [128, 128, 64, 64, 32, 16, 8],
    },
    "discriminator_config": {
        "output_channels": 1,
        "downsample_filters": [64, 128],
        "conv_filters": [32, 128],
    },
}

GRID_SIZE = 128
INPUT_CHANNELS = 3
OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 1

temp_config = {
    "grid_size": GRID_SIZE,
    "layers_per_sample": INPUT_CHANNELS,
    "output_channels": OUTPUT_CHANNELS,
    "input_shape": [GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, INPUT_CHANNELS],
    "target_shape": [GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, OUTPUT_CHANNELS],
}

config.update(temp_config)
config["generator_config"].update(
    {
        "input_shape": [GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, INPUT_CHANNELS],
        "output_channels": OUTPUT_CHANNELS,
    }
)
config["discriminator_config"].update(
    {
        "input_shape": [GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, INPUT_CHANNELS],
    }
)


def _generate_sine_wave_circles_data(config):
    # Generate theta and radius
    theta = jnp.linspace(0, 10 * jnp.pi, config["num_samples"])
    radius_array = jnp.sin(theta)

    radius_array = jnp.abs(jnp.sin(theta))

    grid_size = config["grid_size"]
    num_z_levels = config["num_samples"]

    # Create a grid for x and y coordinates (integers from 0 to grid_size-1)
    x = jnp.arange(grid_size)
    y = jnp.arange(grid_size)
    xx, yy = jnp.meshgrid(x, y)

    # Center the coordinates
    center = grid_size // 2
    # xx_centered = xx - center
    # yy_centered = yy - center

    xx_centered_norm = (xx - center) / (grid_size / 2)
    yy_centered_norm = (yy - center) / (grid_size / 2)

    # Compute distance from the center
    distance = jnp.sqrt(xx_centered_norm**2 + yy_centered_norm**2)

    @jit
    def create_circle(radius):
        # Create a circle with the given radius
        circle = jnp.where(distance <= radius, 1, 0)
        return circle

    # Vectorize the circle creation process for each z level
    sine_wave_circles = vmap(create_circle)(radius_array)

    layers_per_sample = config["layers_per_sample"]
    offset = config["offset"]

    @jit
    def create_layers(circles):
        num_z_levels, grid_size, _ = circles.shape
        assert grid_size == _

        # Calculate the number of layers
        num_layers = num_z_levels - layers_per_sample + 1

        # Create indices for slicing
        indices = jnp.arange(num_layers)[:, None] + jnp.arange(layers_per_sample)

        # Slice the circles array along the first axis
        # layers = circles[indices, :, :]
        layers = jnp.array([circles[idx, :, :] for idx in indices])

        return layers

    layers = create_layers(sine_wave_circles)

    x = layers[:-offset]
    y = sine_wave_circles[offset + layers_per_sample - 1 :]

    assert len(x) == len(y)
    return x, y


def _train_valid_test_split_indices(x, y, config):

    num_samples = len(x)

    # Split the data into training (60%), validation (30%), and test (10%) sets
    train_size = int(config["train_valid_test_splits"][0] * num_samples)
    val_size = int(config["train_valid_test_splits"][1] * num_samples)
    test_size = num_samples - train_size - val_size

    assert num_samples == train_size + val_size + test_size

    # Ensure the splits are consistent and don't overlap
    x_train, y_train = x[:train_size], y[:train_size]
    x_val, y_val = x[train_size : train_size + val_size], y[train_size : train_size + val_size]
    x_test, y_test = x[train_size + val_size :], y[train_size + val_size :]

    # Print the shapes of the datasets to verify the split
    print(f"Training data shape: x_train: {x_train.shape}, y_train: {y_train.shape}")
    print(f"Validation data shape: x_val: {x_val.shape}, y_val: {y_val.shape}")
    print(f"Test data shape: x_test: {x_test.shape}, y_test: {y_test.shape}")

    return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test


def _prepare_sample(x_samples, y_samples, sample_indices):

    def process_sample(x_sample, y_sample):
        x_sample = jnp.transpose(x_sample, (1, 2, 0))
        y_sample = jnp.expand_dims(y_sample, axis=-1)

        x_sample = jnp.expand_dims(x_sample, axis=0)
        y_sample = jnp.expand_dims(y_sample, axis=0)

        return x_sample, y_sample

    if isinstance(sample_indices, int):
        sample_indices = [sample_indices]

    selected_x_samples = jnp.array([x_samples[i] for i in sample_indices])
    selected_y_samples = jnp.array([y_samples[i] for i in sample_indices])

    vmap_process_sample = jax.vmap(process_sample, in_axes=(0, 0))

    inp_combined, re_combined = vmap_process_sample(selected_x_samples, selected_y_samples)

    return jnp.concatenate(inp_combined, axis=0), jnp.concatenate(re_combined, axis=0)


def _evaluate_model(y_true, y_pred):
    metrics = {}
    metrics["mean_absolute_error"] = float(mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred))
    metrics["mean_squared_error"] = float(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    metrics["root_mean_squared_error"] = float(root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    metrics["r2_score"] = float(r2_score(y_true, y_pred))
    return metrics


def _make_prediction(model, model_params, test_input, training_=False):

    return model.apply({"params": model_params}, test_input, mutable=["batch_stats"], training=training_)[0]


x, y = _generate_sine_wave_circles_data(config)
x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test = _train_valid_test_split_indices(x, y, config)

generator = Generator(**config["generator_config"])
discriminator = Discriminator(**config["discriminator_config"])

key = random.PRNGKey(config["random_seed"])
key, key_gen, dropout_key = jax.random.split(key, 3)
sample_index = 10
train_input, train_result = _prepare_sample(x_train, y_train, sample_index)

# Initialize parameters
gen_variables = generator.init(key, train_input, training=True)
disc_variables = discriminator.init(key, train_input, train_result, training=True)


# Create training states for generator and discriminator
gen_tx = optax.adam(learning_rate=config["learning_rate"], b1=config["decay_b1"], b2=config["decay_b2"])
disc_tx = optax.adam(learning_rate=config["learning_rate"], b1=config["decay_b1"], b2=config["decay_b2"])

generator_state = TrainState.create(apply_fn=generator.apply, params=gen_variables["params"], tx=gen_tx)
discriminator_state = TrainState.create(apply_fn=discriminator.apply, params=disc_variables["params"], tx=disc_tx)

# Training loop
batch_size = config["batch_size"]
num_epochs = int(x_train.shape[0] / batch_size)
log_freq_valid = config["log_validation_freq"]
log_eval_valid = config["log_evaluation_freq"]

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    start_idx = epoch * batch_size
    end_idx = start_idx + batch_size
    batch_indices = list(range(start_idx, end_idx))

    train_input, train_result = _prepare_sample(x_train, y_train, batch_indices)

    generator_state, discriminator_state, gen_loss, gan_loss, l1_loss, disc_loss = train_step(
        generator_state, discriminator_state, train_input, train_result, key_gen, config["lambda_constant"]
    )

    logger.info(f"Epoch {epoch}, Gen Loss: {gen_loss}, Disc Loss: {disc_loss}")

    if epoch % log_freq_valid == 0:
        all_y_true = []
        all_y_pred = []
        for valid_index in range(x_val.shape[0]):
            sample_valid_input, sample_valid_result = _prepare_sample(x_val, y_val, valid_index)
            val_prediction = _make_prediction(generator, generator_state.params, sample_valid_input)

            if epoch % log_eval_valid == 0:
                all_y_true.append(sample_valid_result.flatten())
                all_y_pred.append(val_prediction.flatten())

    if epoch % log_eval_valid == 0:
        assert len(all_y_pred) == len(all_y_pred) > 0
        eval_metrics = _evaluate_model(all_y_true, all_y_pred)
        logger.info(eval_metrics)

